# How to code Naïve Bayes using Information Gain (IG)

Tags: machine-learning, naivebayes

I read from a paper that Naive Bayes using IG is the best model for text classification where the dataset is small and has few positives. However, I'm not too sure how to code this specific model using Python. Would this be user TF or Scikit learn and then adjusting a parameter?